# How do I find which class is printing an error?

Tags: java, vert.x

I have a Java program, using Vertx 2, and when I run it, I get a message:

```
% vertx run -cluster com.abc.prep.manager.PrepStartup -cp ./build/libs/Operational-all-1.0.jar -conf safe.conf
Starting clustering... 
No cluster-host specified so using address 172.17.0.1 
[Fatal Error] :6:3: The element type "hr" must be terminated by the matching end-tag "</hr>".
Prep Starting up!
Succeeded in deploying verticle
```

I cannot figure out where that '[Fatal Error]' message is coming from.  If someone knows what vertx is doing (since I think it's coming from there), that would be great.

But my real question is:  How do I find out who is printing that?  What class in which jar?  I can't seem to set a breakpoint in System.out or System.err that catches it (I'm using Intellij).  Can I override (all) output so that it prints a stacktrace?

Comment: It looks like you sent a message and the reply was not xml.  This will happen if you have a security system that intercepts requests and automatically redirects them to a login page.  IBM TAM is a example of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How do you find who is printing that? I can't speak to specifics with Vertx 2, but I've had to track down plenty of mysterious errors. This is my general pattern, applied as far as possible to yours:

1. Get an idea of what the error is. Google the static (would be the same for anybody) elements in the error message. Here, that could be "must be terminated by the matching end-tag". Adding "vertx" to the query gave me some links, but I didn't see any instant answers. I did find out that it's probably an XMLStreamException. You might be able to breakpoint on that.
2. Assuming that didn't work, search your code base by text, looking for that same static text. Armed with the knowledge from your Google investigation, you should be able to narrow down any results to a manageable number to check.
3. If your search finds nothing, make sure you have source files attached for everything in your module that you can get source files for. Then retry step 2.
4. Once you've found the code that throws the error, you should be able to put a breakpoint.

Comment: Ok, I've been narrowing it down.  It looks like it is an XMLStreamException;  however the <hr> is not in any of the code or xml (in mine or the jars).  It appears to be due to a schema reference in one of the xml files in one of the jars that does not resolve, causing an error message being returned.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: And it looks like there is a call to hazelcast.  Wireshark tells me there is an http call:  http://hazelcast.com/version.jsp?version=3.2.3.  The response has a '301 Moved Permanently', and in there it has:  <hr><center>nginx</center>\r\n</body> which is missing a closing </hr> tag.

Comment: depending on what you're configuring with hazelcast and how confident you are in your versioning, you could set hazelcast.version.check.enabled to false. I believe that would stop the checks. (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/hazelcast/9jKfh6-vLbQ). Also, I think that the call should be to this URL http://versioncheck.hazelcast.com/version.jsp?version=3.2.3